# Get selected record Id back to Js from HTML when user click on close(X) button

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a list of data(which is coming from controller to JS and JS to html) which I am using in HTML to display it as the results. I want to perform certain operation when user clicks on close button on the resultant data.

So I tried to use the lightning-pill which has the property as onRemove and I am calling a method in js called handleRemoveSelectedItem.

```
                        <template for:each={existingUsers} for:item="item">
                            <li key={item.id} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">

                                <lightning-pill
                                        label={item.UserOrGroup.Name}
                                        title={item.UserOrGroup.Name}
                                        onremove={handleRemoveSelectedItem}
                                        name={item.id}
                                >
                                    <lightning-icon icon-name={item.icon}></lightning-icon>
                                </lightning-pill>
                            </li>

                        </template>
```

JS code:

```
async handleRemoveSelectedItem(event) {
    this.selectedRecordId = event.detail.value;
    let result = await Server.call(this, remove, {userOrGroupID : this.selectedRecordId,
     recordId: this.recordIds[0]});
}
```

This JS code calls a method from controller to perform certain operation. The problem is I am not getting any value in **this.selectedRecordId**. The result i am seeing it as undefined.Am I missing something? or any other way to show the result data with close box so that I can pass the selection value to JS to perform the operation?

EDIT: Adding screenshot of the result
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be .name instead:

```
this.selectedRecordId = event.detail.name;
```

This wasn't clear from the documentation, so I just built a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/sUs0npBga/1/edit).

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much @sfdcfox. Also, is there other way to display the result with close mark apart from using lightning-pill?  I tried to use the lightning-datatable but the result is coming with header. I added the screenshot also to the question

Comment: @KSL If datatable doesn't work, then you may need to write your own. You can use lightning-button-icon to display a button similar to the close icon with an action, or build your own with lightning-icon to display the icon as you wish. There's many possible alternatives.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again. I will create my own table and use that for display purpose.